# Use the chain provider defined from a service

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, symfony-security

I use multiple user providers in my app:

```yml
security:
    providers:
        chain_provider:
            chain:
                providers: [entity, json]
        entity:
            id: myapp.entity.user_provider
        json:
            id: myapp.json.user_provider
```

Now I need to load a user from a service

```yml
services:
    myapp.my.service:
        class: AppBundle\Services\My
        argument: [@the.defined.chain.provider]
```

```php
// AppBundle\Services\My
namespace AppBundle\Services;
class My
{
    public function loadUser($username)
    {
        return $this->userProvider->loadUserByUsername($username);
    }
}
```

How can I use the chain provider explicitly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at [the code of SecurityBundle](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/src/Symfony/Bundle/SecurityBundle/DependencyInjection/SecurityExtension.php#L533-L544), you just can use the service `security.user.provider.concrete.{name}`, so in your case `security.user.provider.concrete.chain_provider`

Comment: Interesting, will it automatically get the providers array as argument ?

Comment: Yes. Basicly, you got bundles, which define base services and configuration options. Then it use your configuration to configure its services/parameters in the container.
Here you configure a chain provider named `chain_provider` with two providers, Symfony will know that it have to create a service `security.user.provider.concrete.chain_provider` and use your configured providers as the first argument of it.

Comment: Fine ! I'll check that too, Thanks

Comment: If my answer helped you, can you please validate it?

Comment: I sure will when I'll be able to check

Answer (score 1):

The providers are initialised as services and you can do the same with the Chain provider:

```
services:
    the.defined.chain.provider:
        class: Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\ChainUserProvider
        arguments: [ [ @myapp.entity.user_provider, @myapp.json.user_provider ] ]
```

Then in your security.yml file, replace your providers with:

```
security:
    providers:
        default: 
            id: the.defined.chain.provider
```

And in your services file just keep your example for `myapp.my.service`

So you'd be creating the user provider chain yourself as a service (which is effectively what the security bundle does with your configuration) and using it in two places.